# GPS location is on/off in iphone for my app

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, cllocationmanager

i am check `GPS` location is `on/off` to use this code

```
BOOL servicesEnabled = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
```

it work correctly when on/off LocationServices in iphone,but i am set off LocationServices for my app it return only `servicesEnabled` to `YES`,that time `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]`  how to check `locationServicesEnabled` in my app
**Ex:** i am disable my app location services like as instagram, how to solve this problem to check `LocationServices` in particular app in iphone or ipad?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your `CLLocationManagerDelegate's locationManager: didFailWithError:` method and check for a `kCLErrorDenied` error to see if the user denied location services.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

    // Set a movement threshold for new events.

    locationManager.distanceFilter = 500;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager

     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    // If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

if location service disable for your app then its give you error

```
Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)"
```