# Event for gps on and off in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gps

If user on the gps i want perform some operation and if gps is off by the user.then need to perform certain operation. Is there any events in xamarin.forms for gps on/off.

Comment: there are numerous existing questions that address how to do this in Android and iOS.  You would need to write platform code in order to do this in XF

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said, platform code could achieve gps event.

On Android,you can refer to this question [Event for gps on/off state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611824/event-for-gps-on-off-state-change)

And on ios, you can check this [GPS location is on/off in iphone for my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608970/gps-location-is-on-off-in-iphone-for-my-app)

Here is dependency service document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction